# antd checkbox with label inside

Tags: antd

I couldn’t find a way to put a label inside the antd checkbox, removing the tick and replacing it with the label, in this case a letter, as it appears in the image[antd checkbox customized tick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iX5Y5.jpg)

maybe someone already went through this same case and can give me an idea where to review.

thanks, cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here its how i managed to match the requeriments :

```
const StyledCheckBox = styled(Checkbox)`
  &.ant-checkbox-wrapper {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;

    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  }

  &.ant-checkbox-wrapper-checked {
    background-color: #1890ff;
    color: #fff;
  }

  .ant-checkbox {
    display: none;
  }
`;
```

and then just group that checkboxes

```
<Checkbox.Group style={{ width: "100%" }}>
              <Row>
                <Col span={4}>
                  <MyCheckbox value="1">L</MyCheckbox>
                </Col>
                <Col span={4}>
                  <MyCheckbox value="2">M</MyCheckbox>
                </Col>
                <Col span={4}>
                  <MyCheckbox value="3">M</MyCheckbox>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </Checkbox.Group>
```